# push a view from an actionscript class

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

I have a remoteobject class that handles all interactive with my remote data service. each time a call is made the dataservice checks that the user has a valid session. if they don't it won't run the requested method and it returns a fail. I can capture this fail in the fault handler. What I want to do it if it happens is push the login screen to the user.

I have tried the following

```
            var navigator:ViewNavigator;
            navigator.activeView.navigator.pushView(views.LoginScreen);
```

But this is not working and fails with  Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. which makes sense. so my question is how can I get a reference to the current running view navigator object and push the view?

Thanks

As requested here is the full remote object class

package remoting
{
    import events.RemoteExceptionEvent;

```
import flash.events.*;

import mx.managers.CursorManager;
import mx.messaging.ChannelSet;
import mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel;
import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

import spark.components.ViewNavigator;

import views.FirstTime.ValidateUser;

/**
 * Super class for all remote services that contains some generic methods.
 */
public class RemoteService extends EventDispatcher

{
    private static var REMOTE_EXCEPTION:String = "Remote exception";
    private static var NO_MESSAGE:String = "10001";

    protected var remoteObject:RemoteObject;

    private var amfChannelSet:ChannelSet;

    /**
     * Constructor accepting an id and destination for the actual RemoteObject to create. An event listener
     * is added for exceptions.
     * @param id String representing the id of the new RemoteObject to create
     * @param destination String representing the destination of the RemoteObject to create
     * @param amfChannelId String representing the Channel of the RemoteObject to create
     * @param amfChannelEndpoint String representing the Endpoint URI of the RemoteObject to create
     */
    public function RemoteService( serviceId:String
                                   , serviceDestination:String
                                     , amfChannelId:String
                                       , amfChannelEndpoint:String
    ) 
    {
        // Create a runtime Channelset for given Channel ID and Endpoinr URI
        var amfChannel:AMFChannel = new AMFChannel(amfChannelId, amfChannelEndpoint);
        amfChannelSet = new ChannelSet();
        amfChannelSet.addChannel(amfChannel);

        // Create the remoteObject instance
        this.remoteObject = new RemoteObject(serviceId);
        this.remoteObject.channelSet = amfChannelSet;
        this.remoteObject.destination = serviceDestination;
        this.remoteObject.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,onRemoteException);
        this.remoteObject.setCredentials('test','test');

    }

    /**
     * generic fault event handler for all remote object actions. based on the received message/code an action
     * is taken, mostly throwing a new event.
     * @param event FaultEvent received for handling
     */
    public function onRemoteException(event:FaultEvent):void {
        trace('code : ' + event.fault.faultCode +
            ', message : ' + event.fault.faultString +
            ',detail : ' + event.fault.faultDetail);

            trace('fodun: ' + event.fault.faultDetail.indexOf("Authentication"));

        if (event.fault.faultDetail.indexOf("Authentication") > 0)
        {

            var navigator:ViewNavigator;

             navigator.activeView.navigator.pushView(views.LoginScreen);



        }
        else  if (event.fault.faultString == REMOTE_EXCEPTION) {
            EventDispatcher(
                new RemoteExceptionEvent(RemoteExceptionEvent.REMOTE_EXCEPTION,
                    "unknown problem occurred during a remote call : " + event.fault.message));
        } else if (event.fault.faultCode == NO_MESSAGE) { 
            EventDispatcher(
                new RemoteExceptionEvent(RemoteExceptionEvent.REMOTE_EXCEPTION,
                    event.fault.faultString));
        } else {

            EventDispatcher((
                new RemoteExceptionEvent(RemoteExceptionEvent.REMOTE_EXCEPTION,
                    "unknown runtime problem occurred during a remote call : " + event.fault.message)));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: We need more code to understand where you want to access what you want.

Comment: Code added to the main post. let me know if there is anything else you need to see. I just want to send the user to the login screen if the credentials are wrong.

Comment: What do you expect your navigator instance to be ? You can't declare something and consider it is something global in your application this way. I guess there is another place in your code where you declare a navigator, am I wrong ? You have to make the difference between display components that will handle your application's look, and service (for instance) that will handle data reading.

Comment: I think that is the crux of the problem. I don't know how to get a reference to it. I don't know where  the viewnavigator is declared I assume it is created as part of the ViewNavigatorApplication. I don't care that much about how I do it. I just want to be able to push the view from the class so that I can handle the lack of authentication. I could dispatch an event that i listen for in my view but that would mean for all views I would have to include the same code. I was hoping to centralise the exception handling.

Comment: You don't know where the viewNavigator is created ? Where do you create your view ? Can you please post a screenshot of your project files ? You can't create an application without creating views !!!

Comment: I do create views under a views folder. using <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"> I am saying I don't explicitly create a view navigator. The application is created using <s:ViewNavigatorApplication>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing your view or whatever visual components from within a RemoteService class is not a good way to deal with MVC applications. What you want to do is to dispatch an event in your RemoteService class that basically says "authentication has failed". Then, in your view, you'll listen for this event and interpret it as a need to display the login screen. See ?

Comment: yeah  I was thinking along those lines I was just trying to find a way to not have to put a fault handler in each and every view. but if that is the best way then I will do that